# C++ class template, how to overload [ ] operator in a specific stuation?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a class template with non-void type parameter

```
template <typename T, unsigned int n>
class Array
{
private:
    T* value;
public:
    Array()
   {
        this->value = new T[n];
   }

    ~Array() {
        delete [] this->value;
   }
    Array(const Array & arr){
        this->value = new T[n];
        int a = n;
        int b = 0;
        while(a != 0)
       {
             this->value[b] = arr.value[b];
             b++;
             a--;
       }
   }
   Array& operator=(const Array& arr)
   {
       int a = n;
       int b = 0;
       while(a != 0)
      {
            this->value[b] = arr.value[b];
            b++;
            a--;
      }
      return *this;
   }

   T& operator[](int a)
   {
      return this->value[a];
   }

   unsigned int size()
   {
      return n;
   }
};
```

Above is my class template and below is a class named "Test".

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "Test::Test()" << std::endl; }

    Test(Test const&) { std::cout << "Test::Test(Test const&)" << std::endl; }

    ~Test() { std::cout << "Test::~Test()" << std::endl; }

    Test& operator=(Test const&)
    {
         std::cout << "Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)" << std::endl;
         return *this;
    }

    void print() const { std::cout << "Test::print() const" << std::endl;    }
    void print() { std::cout << "Test::print()" << std::endl; }
};
```

And in my main.cpp file, I wrote this

```
int main(int, char*[])
{
    Array<Test, 3> arr_1;
    arr_1[1].print();

    Test& t1 = arr_1[2];
    t1.print();

    return 0;
 }
```

What I want to do is,

when I call `arr_1[1].print();`,

it has to use `print() const` function from my "Test" class

and when I do `Test& t1 = arr_1[2];`

and call `t1.print();`,

it has to use `print()` (non-const function).

I don't understand how I can overload [] operator to 
return a const value and a non-const value.

Am I missing a method from my class template?
Or my overload [] operator implementation is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I have to do the test with "Test" class. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @NeilButterworth, it's actually a practice question from my class. Sorry for not specifying it!

Comment: It seems you want an expression `arr_1[i]` to return a const reference sometimes and a non-const reference other times. I don't see how this is possible - how would it know when to return which? Why do you want `arr_1[1].print();` to call a const version of `print()`, when values in the array are in fact non-const?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, Hello again! and thank you for the comment, actually, it's a practice question from my class and it's is asked to do so. That is exactly what I was thinking and wanted to find out if it was even possible.

Comment: The requirement doesn't make any sense. Either you misunderstood the assignment, or it's a trick question.

Comment: Are you sure you understood the question correctly? This sounds like a lot like an assignment that asks you to implement a `operator[]` that returns a const reference for a const array and a non-const reference otherwise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'll check again with my professor! Thank you for clarifying it out!

Comment: @Knoep Thank you for the comment! It's seems like the requirement is not possible.

Comment: There is no overloading by return value in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'const print' is used if the object has the 'const' qualifier on it. Otherwise the other form is used. In your case none of the 'Test' instances are 'const', so non-const versions of print are used:

```
T& operator[](int a)
...
arr[1].print(); 
Test &t1 = arr[2];
t1.print();
```

in the above example arr[1] is no-const, and t1 is not either, so both will use the non-const version of print.

In the following example though, the 't2' will be const and will use the 'const version of the print function:

```
T& operator[](int a)
...
arr[1].print(); 
const Test &t2 = arr[2];
t2.print();
```

In both cases the operator is non-const. However if you make it to return 'const' than both variants will use 'const' version of the print:

```
const T& operator[](int a)
...
arr[1].print(); 
const Test &t1 = arr[2];
t1.print();
```

Well, in the latter case declaring t1 as non-const will cause compilation failure, because you try to derefecence a const  value to a non-const.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was away! sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could have `Array::operator[]` return a `const T&`, which would force the `const` version of `print` to be called from the returned reference. But in that case the line `Test& t1 = arr_1[2];` would fail because you can't assign a const reference to a non-const reference without `const_cast`.

Comment: Hi Mark! and thank you for answering to my question!

Comment: I've tried with const T&, and that caused the same problem. That is the main reason why I decided to post this question! Thanx again!